# Preserve time while updating cookie

Tags: php, cookies

Just a quick question. Is there any easy way how to not to change expire time in cookie while updating?

Let's say I have a cookie set to expire in 24 hours. But in the same date i update the cookie few times. But i still want the cookie expire at the same time after 24 hours.

Detailed example:

Cookie "counter" should expire on 23.07.2011 10:00. Now after one hour because of some action I update value of this cookie. if i set the time for 24 hours it would expire on 23.07.2011 11:00, but i need the expire time to stay at 23.07.2011 10:00.

Is there any easy way? Only way i can think of is to have another cookie with stored expire time, but i would swear there must be easier way, just missing something ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using another cookie, you could store the expiration date along with the cookie value:

```
$expire = time()+$maxage;
setcookie($name, "$expire:$value", $expire);
```

Then you can get both data using [`explode`](http://php.net/explode):

```
list($expire, $_COOKIE[$name]) = explode(':', $_COOKIE[$name], 2);
setcookie($name, "$expire:$new_value", $expire);
```

Comment: yeah problem with this is that the cookie is already array, serialized into string. There might be some problems, but good idea for simple cookies for sure!

Comment: @Tom: You can do this with any string value. If it’s serialized data, unserialize it after splitting it.

Comment: Maybe I can use another deliminer because serialize use ":" . I will see what it can use

Comment: @Tom: You can use any delimiter you want. And with 2 as *limit* value it should only split the cookie value in at most 2 parts, leaving the serialized value unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

PHP (and Javascript) cannot retrieve the expiry time of a cookie.  Only the cookie name/value pairs are known to them.  You really do need to store the original expiry either in another cookie, or in a database table at the time of the original `setcookie()` call.  On subsequent modifications to that cookie, use the expiry you've stored in the database (or other cookie).